# Changing working directory in tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I don't know how to do this in tortoise SVN so I would like to ask for help.

Say I checked out a copy from my SVN repository and put it in my PC directory
at C:\MyProject.

However there are batch files in my project hierarchy that requires that I should check out the files in a directory called C:\MyProject\MySubDirectory

The batch files wont work unless I check it out in this folder C:\MyProject\MySubDirectory.  Is there a command in tortoise svn to transfer my working files into another directory in my pc without synching again from the repository?  It took me a day to sync all files so I am trying to find a way for this.

I tried to manually copy all my files and folder from C:\MyProject and create a folder MySubDirectory under it but I am losing SVN command or svn is losing a way to manage my files.

Any hints?

Comment: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html

Answer (score 2):

Yiu just need to move/copy whole you checkout folder (contain hidden `.svn` subfolder) to new location.

Comment: Tried it but SVN does not recognize my files as being managed.  When I try to do something or edit something, the commit option is not available in tortoisesvn.  Only the checkout option

Comment: Check hidden `.svn` is exist?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

1: Rename `MyProject` to `MySubDirectory`

2: Create a folder `MyProject`inside `C:\`

3: Cut `MySubDirectory` and paste it inside `MyProject`